# Dealing with dylibs when distributing python packages

Tags: cython, portability, distutils, dylib

I need to run certain commands after building a Cython module with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or an equivalent command. Is this possible?

Specifically here is the situation:
I am working on a Cython program for osx. It links to certain `.dylib` files in my home directory and to get the program to build, you either have to run

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/parent/dir
```

(which is a hassle) or include a directive in `setup.py` to run

```
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/my.dylib /path/to/my.dylib
```

What this basically does is it tells the binary where to look for the `dylib`. Neither option is ideal, but the latter seems slightly more portable. Right now I just added these instructions to the bottom of `setup.py`, but this is still not portable: let's say I package and upload my package as follows:

```
python setup.py sdist  # I think this collects source files into a .tar
python setup.py bdist_wheel  # I think this builds a binary. This is where I assume the post-compilation stuff should happen.
twine upload dist/*   # This puts stuff up on PyPi.
```

Now, I have read the documentation and a few tutorials, and I am admittedly still not 100% sure what these commands do. But I know that if subsequently, in another project, I run

```
pip install mypackage
```

The dylib issue rears its ugly head:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/my/module.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: @executable_path/my.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/my/module.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The solution it seems is to add some kind of automatic post-compilation direction to setup.py to indicate that the `install_name_tool` operation needs to be performed. Assuming this is possible, how would one do it? Ideally I would like to use off-the-shelf `Cython.Build.cythonize` and `setuptools.Extension`, but maybe I need to do something more customized. Thanks for your suggestions!

## Solution

Danny correctly pointed out that running `install_name_tool` is not a portable solution and instead the dylib should somehow be included in the package. [`delocate`](https://github.com/matthew-brett/delocate) is the tool for the job, but the first challenge that I encountered was that `delocate` doesn't work with `@executable_path`:

```
❯ delocate-wheel -w fixed_wheels -v dist/*.whl
Fixing: dist/my-package-1.0.9-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_12_x86_64.whl
/Users/ethan/virtualenvs/my-package/lib/python3.6/site-packages/delocate/delocating.py:71: UserWarning: Not processing required path @executable_path/my.dylib because it begins with @
  'begins with @'.format(required))
```

Using `otool`, I was able to verify that the `id` of `my.dylib` uses `@executable_path`:

```
❯ otool -L my.dylib
my.dylib:
    @executable_path/my.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1258.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

To get rid of `@executable_path` I ran the following:

```
❯ install_name_tool -id my.dylib my.dylib
```

Now look at the output of `otool -L`:

```
❯ otool -L my.dylib
my.dylib:
    my.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1258.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

In general, this is not a good `id` to use for a dylib, but it is enough for `delocate-wheel` to work with. I rebuilt my `.whl`:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

And now when I ran `delocate_wheel`:

```
❯ delocate-wheel -w fixed_wheels -v dist/*.whl
Fixing: dist/my.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
...    
delocate.delocating.DelocationError: library "/Users/ethan/my-package/my.dylib" does not exist
```

This clearly tells us where `delocate` expects to find `my.dylib`. So I copied `my.dylib` to `/Users/ethan/my-package/my.dylib` and reran the command:

```
❯ delocate-wheel -w fixed_wheels -v dist/*.whl
Fixing: dist/my.whl
Copied to package .dylibs directory:
  /Users/ethan/my-package/my.dylib
```

Success! What is this `.dylibs` directory? I ran `tar -xvf my.whl` to unpack the wheel and examine its contents:

```
❯ tree -a fixed_wheels/my-package
fixed_wheels/my-package
├── .dylibs
│   └── my.dylib
├── __init__.py
└── package.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

As you can see, the `my.dylib` has been copied into a `.dylibs/` directory that gets packaged in the `my.whl`. After uploading `my.whl` to pypi, I was able to download and run the code just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [delocate](https://github.com/matthew-brett/delocate) and the Linux equivalent [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel).

Rather than having to change link loader paths at runtime, the delocate tool embeds third party libraries into a wheel and adjusts load time paths accordingly.

The result is a distributable binary wheel with all dependent libraries correctly included.

Setting runtime load paths is not portable and will not work across python versions or machine architectures.

For example for the above, after a wheel is created by `python setup.py bdist_wheel` run:

`delocate-wheel -w fixed_wheels <wheel file>`

A fixed wheel file will be placed under `fixed_wheels` directory. Run with `-v` to see what libraries it has embedded.